# UNIX read behavior

Tags: c, linux, unix

I wrote this small code to ascertain read behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main ()
{
  ssize_t ret;
  int fd;
  char str[30] = {0};
  off_t lret

  fd = open("./sample", O_RDWR);
  printf("File descriptor = %d\n",fd);

  lret = lseek(fd,LONG_MAX,SEEK_SET);
  printf("%ld\n",lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR));

  ret = read(fd, str, 20);
  if (ret == -1) {
     perror("read error");
  }
  else {
     printf("%ld\n",ret);
     printf("%s\n",str);
  }

  ret = write(fd, "bye", 3);
  if (ret == -1) {
     perror("write error");
  }
  else
     printf("%ld\n",ret);

  printf("%ld\n",lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR));
  close (fd);

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
$ cat sample
HELLO$ ./a.out
File descriptor = 3
4294967295
read error: Invalid argument
write error: Invalid argument
4294967295
$ ll sample
-rw-r--r--. 1 bruce stud 5 Jan 14 17:25 sample
```

But if I change lseek statement to

```
ret = lseek(fd,5,SEEK_SET);
```

read returns 0

```
$ ./a.out
File descriptor = 3
5
0

3
8
$ cat sample
HELLObye$ ll sample
-rw-r--r--. 1 bruce stud 8 Jan 14 17:26 sample
```

Why does read behave like this?

Comment: You need 64 bit read/write I/O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the value returned by `lseek` is a `off_t`, not a `size_t`. The difference is that off_t is signed. When you take a signed value and make it unsigned, it appears like a large positive number.

I would expect that "LONG_MAX" is not actually `4294967295`, but either `2147483647` (2^31-1) or a much larger number. So the `4294967295` comes from a -1 [it is 2^32-1, which is indeed the same as -1 in 32-bit math].

In other words, you are getting an error from `lseek`.

Comment: `ssize_t` is also signed, like `off_t`.  It might not be the same size as `off_t`, however, and both might be different from `long`.

Comment: On my system both ssize_t and off_t are 8 bytes long. #   define LONG_MAX     9223372036854775807L

Comment: The key point here is not the size of `off_t`, but the fact that `off_t` is signed and `size_t` is not.

Comment: Ok. Here is what I did:   off_t lret;
  lret = lseek(fd,LONG_MAX,SEEK_SET);
  if (lret == -1)
     perror("seek error");
and I got "seek error: Success"

Comment: and how do you explain the value of printf("%ld\n",lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR)); being 4294967295. If there was an error in seek the value of file pointer should be 0, right?

Comment: How strange. Not sure how that works out - as LONG_MAX should be a positive signed value, off_t is a signed...

Comment: There is clearly some strangeness with signs and sizes of variables here - 4294967295 is definitely a -1 in 32-bit numbers. I'm not sure what's going on exactly, but something is turning your 64-bit number inta 32-bit number, and then you get an error when operating on the file that is 4GB larger than it just was... Which may well be a valid point too - depends on what filesystem, OS, diskspace, etc is there.

Comment: I get a bunch of warnings from gcc about "%ld used with 'int'" and the like - and perhaps more importantly, "implict declaration of function lseek" and same for "read", "write". I shall fix those warnings and get back to you.

Comment: After adding "unistd.h", I get no warnings, but the output indicates the seek didn't work right. 
"File descriptor = 3
0
6
HELLO

3
9" Adding a printf("ret=%zd\n", ret) shows -1 on my system. Which is a Fedora 16, 64-bit.

Comment: Hmmm. Matt, is it an error to seek past the maximum file size allowed by the file system?

Comment: All I get is EINVAL (invalid argument). I'm guessing that is what happens yes. But you should try compiling with warnings - it's possible that your arguments aren't interpreted correctly, and thus the function isn't working right at all.

Comment: I did compile with -Wall. I got no warning after including unistd.h.

Comment: And the results remain? What OS, what filesystem, any restrictions on your disk?

Answer (score 1):

Odd error results.  What actual OS are you using?  I added a check `if (ret == -1) perror("lseek error");` just after the first lseek for better error checking.

On linux I see:

```
File descriptor = 3
lseek error: Invalid argument
0
5
HELLO
3
8
```

On OpenBSD I see:

```
File descriptor = 3
9223372036854775807
read error: File too large
write error: File too large
9223372036854775807
```

...both of which seem like reasonable responses

Comment: lseek has return type of off_t which is 8 bytes on my system. ret is of int type. That is what it prints an error on lseek. There is actually no error on lseek.

Comment: I think write succeeds in the first case when you run on Linux. I want to see if I seek past the maximum file size what happens on read and write. If I seek past the file size (not maximum file size), read returns 0. I think it should return -1 here also.