# UNIX lseek/read/write behavior

Tags: linux, unix, file-io, seek

If I have a file of size 5 and I use lseek to seek to position 10 and then read 1 byte from this position using read, the return value of read system call is 0.
I want to know the return value of lseek/read/write in the following case:
If I seek past the maximum file size allowed by the file system and then perform read. Can we  lseek to this position/Is it an error? If not if I do a read here what will be the return value of read? 0 or -1?

Comment: `read` returns the number of bytes that were actually read. 0 sounds appropriate to me.

Comment: Or there's the possibility that the seek itself may fail and you'll therefore simply read at the old position. But @Carl is right, you should try it and see.

Comment: I did try it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327953/unix-read-behavior

Answer (score 5):

The [POSIX specs for `lseek()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/lseek.html) state that you are allowed to set the position beyond the end of the file:

> The lseek() function shall allow the file offset to be set beyond the end of the existing data in the file.

It only complains if the resulting position is beyond the bounds of the `off_t` variable type returned from `lseek()`. There seem to be no error messages specified which indicate things like "beyond your process-specific limit" or "beyond the capacity of the filesystem itself".

---

However, trying to extend the file after that seek with a `write()` can return the `EFBIG` error code, again [according to POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html). Best bet would be to actually try this and see what the behaviour is, *especially* since Linux doesn't necessarily comply with POSIX in all cases - in other words, the behaviour may be different between POSIX-compliant UNIX systems and Linux.

---

The [POSIX `read()` specs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html) are quite adamant about what happens:

> No data transfer shall occur past the current end-of-file. If the starting position is at or after the end-of-file, 0 shall be returned.

Hence, you should get back zero since, by definition, if you've done an `lseek()` beyond the capacity of the filesystem, you're assuredly beyond the end of the file (you can't create files bigger than the filesystem allows).